# Auto login with FileVault in El Captain

Tags: terminal, macos, password, filevault

When using File Vault on El Capitan, is there any way to disable the Auto Login, so when you start up it loads straight away without needing a password.

If not, then is possible to set it so when you enter a password it goes straight to the desktop and skips the loading bar. (i.e. so it preloads before the password is entered)

I understand why a password is needed, but it is overkill for my situation.

I'm guessing the answer is probably "no", but I thought there might be a terminal command or some other trick.

Comment: You can see [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/217673/81404) question from yesterday, per my answer it is possible to issue an ACPI restart command and not require a password on startup, but no other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A permanent work around would be to disable FileVault, which has the serious downside of compromising your encryption entirely, as described in this [Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201476)

For a one-off you can use the [`fdesetup` command](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408214502/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202918) to reboot and bypass the user login step. This is designed for unattended reboots and works well in my experience without compromising your encrypted system.  Run the following command in Terminal:

`sudo fdesetup authrestart`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. FileVault encrypts the entire startup volume, and therefore cannot do much of anything (including logging you in, or even loading the OS) until a valid decrypt password is given. Once you supply your password, then it's able to load the OS and log you in.